# iOS - Maximum file size we can transfer through web services in iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, file-transfer, filesize

I am working on web services in iOS App.

I want to download and upload a document file through web service in my iPhone Application which contains XML data only.

My question is, upto what maximum file size I can transfer through web service in my app.

Thanks.

Comment: It dependes on your server side settings. By default is 5 MB. If you want to send more sized data you need to tell your server admin.

Comment: @Ashish P. Thank you for the information